# DetachedCriteria setFetchMode associationPath - Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

The setFetchMode in DetachedCriteria takes "String associationPath" as an argument. I couldnt find what it is. Do i need to send the other entity name or table name or any other value for this argument? I tried calling with a random value, it didnt throw any exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is path to the persistent attribute, exactly as with normal [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFetchMode%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.FetchMode%29).

For example:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Group.class);
...
criteria.setFetchMode("members", FetchMode.JOIN);
```